# Can a Kotlin interface cache a value?

Tags: java, kotlin, observable

I really like using default implementations for interfaces in Kotlin, especially for common patterns like Observable.  Here's my interface,

```
interface Observable<T>{

    // How do I cache this?
    val observers: MutableList<Observer<T>>
        get() = LinkedList<>()

    fun addObserver(o:Observer<T>){
        observers.add(o)
    }

    fun removeObserver(o:Observer<T>){
        observers.remove(o)
    }

    fun notifyObservers(u:T){
        for (o in observers){
            o.update(u)
        }
    }

}
```

The interface refers to a list of `observers`, but the `get()` call is returning a new `LinkedList()` each time.  How can I cache the value of `observers` so that it's only created once?  I've tried using [kotlin-lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), but either can't get the syntax right, or it's not meant for interfaces.  My IDE complains "Delegated properties are not allowed in interfaces."

**UPDATE**

Based on Yoav's answer, I've change my interface to

```
interface Observable<T>{
    val observers: MutableList<Observer<T>>
}
```

And then in the implementing class,

```
class MyObservable : Observable<String>

   private val _observers = LinkedList<Observer<String>>()

   override val observers: MutableList<Observer<String>>
       get() = _observers
```

Any tips to make this more succinct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Kotlin docs:

> Interfaces in Kotlin are very similar to Java 8. They can contain
>   declarations of abstract methods, as well as method implementations.
>   What makes them different from abstract classes is that interfaces
>   cannot store state.

Interface can't hold any state as they are fully abstract. Perhaps you should use an `abstract class` in order to cache the values?

See [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184945/why-is-an-interface-in-java-not-allowed-to-have-state) question for more information about the reason for interfaces being stateless.

> An interface is a contract specifying what its implementer promises to
>   be able to do. It does not need to specify state because state is an
>   implementation detail and only serves to constrain implementers in how
>   this contract is fulfilled. If you want to specify state you might
>   want to rethink you use of interfaces and look at abstract base
>   classes instead.

Comment: Thanks.  I've updated my question to reflect my concrete implementation.  If you have any suggestions, please feel free to add to this answer.

Comment: @AdamHughes why not just `override val observers: MutableList<Observer<String>> = LinkedList()`? Why do you need an explicit backing field?

Comment: Also, you can keep your helping function in the interface, or even better: declare them outside as extension methods :)

Comment: Yoav, if I set `val observers = LinkedList()` won't this generate a new LinkedList() each time the getter is called?  I want to reuse this list.  I will look into extension methods, I'm not really familiar with what you're proposing (new to kotlin)

Comment: No, only if you use the getter syntax `get() = LinkedList()`

Comment: Ah thanks, I was using incorrect syntax when I originally attempted that.  I was doing `val observers: LinkedList()` instead of 'val observers = LinkedList()`

Answer (score 0):

While you cannot create stateful variables on an interface directly, you can achieve the same result by defining a companion object containing a cache and do a dynamic lookup on `this`. Using your example:

```
interface Observable<T>{
  // How do I cache this?
  val observers: MutableList<Observer<T>>
    get() = cache.computeIfAbsent(this) { mutableListOf<Observer<T>>() } as MutableList<Observer<T>>

  fun addObserver(o:Observer<T>){
    observers.add(o)
  }

  fun removeObserver(o:Observer<T>){
    observers.remove(o)
  }

  fun notifyObservers(u:T){
    for (o in observers){
      o.update(u)
    }
  }

  companion object {
    val cache = WeakHashMap<Observable<*>, MutableList<*>>()
  }
}
```

If you want a more efficient cache, you can use a library like [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine).

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this some more, I discovered a nice pattern. First I tried the direct approach:

```kotlin
interface A {
  val prop = compute() // Nope: Property initializers are not allowed in interfaces
  /*...*/
}
```

As you mentioned, it can be done using a custom accessor but must be recomputed each time:

```kotlin
interface A {
  val prop get() = compute() // OK, but recomputed each time someProperty is read
  /*...*/
}
```

Then I thought, perhaps we can use a delegated property instead? But this is not allowed either:

```kotlin
interface A {
  val prop by { compute() } // Not allowed: Delegated properties are not allowed in interfaces
  /*...*/
}
```

Finally, I found you can achieve the same result by creating a property extension with a delegate:

```kotlin
interface A { /*...*/ }
val A.prop by lazy { compute() }
```

From a usage standpoint, you just import the extension and can access `a.prop` as usual.